# Maintaining similar copies of a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I work on a project with a large amount of stored procedures (~1500). Most of these stored procedures contain USE "databaseName" statements sprinkled throughout.

The problem: The project I'm currently working on requires me to maintain two versions of a database. In one version I have a base set of data that should not be altered, and which I can use when needed. In the other version is the data from the first database, plus changes to that data.

Is anyone aware of a simple method of changing which database is used at a given time?

One option is backing up and restoring the original database under a different name. However, doing this will break the USE  statements in the stored procedures. I could replace all cases of the old database name in the stored procedures with a the new name, but false positives might cause problems. Another option is making a copy of the entire SQL Server instance, and connecting to that copy. From searching online, doing this looks like a fairly involved process.

Surely this is a common problem and I'm overlooking a simple way of handling this problem? I don't see anything yet though, from internet searches, aside from the above two options.

Comment: Are you sure you have USE [databasename] in your stored procedures? Last I checked this is not allowed. Or do you mean select x from [databaseA].[schema].[table] join [database].schema.table

Answer (score 1):

It is a common problem but it has a common solution. Maintain different environments. Normally you have DEV/TEST/PROD environments and you point your app at whichever one you want to use at the time (normally you move from DEV > TEST > PROD)

Can you expand on "From searching online, doing this looks like a fairly involved process." ?

This is the way I see it working:

1. Install another instance of SQL Server (this could even be the free edition, SQL Express). This only needs to be done once
2. Restore your alternative dataset into here
3. Point your app at it

The difficult part is setting up a framework for accessing the difficult environments, and making sure the data in each is as you require. Are there any constraints around pointing your app at a different DB server?